# AVPlayerItem and KVO - am i missing something?

Tags: ios, media, avfoundation

so in the init of a simple Controller i have this code:

```
self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
[self.playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
```

which should try and load media from the url, right? i'm implemeting

```
observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:
```

however, this method is never called. Clueless?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

playerItem starts working after being assigned to a AVPlayer object (duh)

```
self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.playerItem];
```